# unable to copy file from docker container to EC2 instance

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have a Jenkins container running inside an EC2-instance and I am trying to copy few files from the Jenkins container to the EC2-instance but it's not working as expected.

I am using the below command to copy the file from the EC2 instance to the Jenkins docker container which is working as expected

```
docker cp ./DummyFile 0011c1951fa6:/home/jenkins
```

But when I use the cp command to copy the file to the EC2 instance instead of copying the file to the EC2-instance directory it's creating the testfile1 inside the Jenkins container itself.

```
docker cp 0011c1951fa6:/home/jenkins/testfile /home/jenkins/testfile1
```

I have tried the volume mount which is working as expected, but I do not want to mount the volume every time the container is launched. Can someone explain me to understand why the copy command is not copying the files to Ec2 instance and how to resolve this issue?. Thank you !!

Comment: What’s the distinction between “EC2 instance” and “EC2 host directory” (those sound the same to me)?  Where is the file ending up, and where do you want it?

Comment: @David Maze - Yes, its the same..ideally i want the file to be copied to the EC2 instance, but the file is copied to the jenkins container itself. After executing the command i can see testfile & testfile1 file in the jenkins container directory /home/jenkins/ . No files are copied/created in the underlying EC2 instance

Comment: After you run the last command, what is in `/home/jenkins` on the host?  Does it report any errors?

Comment: No errors are reported.. i am seeing testfile and testfile1 in the /home/jenkins folder in the container. No filed are copied to the ec2 instance

Comment: And you’re logged into a shell on the EC2 host (not a `docker exec` emergency-debug shell in the Jenkins container) when you’re running `docker cp`?  There’s only one Docker daemon involved (you’re not running an additional Docker daemon within Jenkins)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct...no additional docker daemon is running within Jenkins and I have logged into a shell on the EC2 instance. Also I have mounted the /var/run/docker.sock volume to the jenkins docker container

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the destination folder exists. In your example the "test" folder should exist under /home for the command to work.

I just tested this with a jenkins:latest image and it worked both ways for me.

[docker cp command reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description)

Comment: Thanks @sxm1972. But I am still having an issue in copying the files to underlying EC2 instance. After executing the command i can see testfile & testfile1 file in the jenkins container directory /home/jenkins/ . No files are copied/created in the underlying EC2 instance.